# Android text style missing light, medium, thin,

Tags: android, textview, typeface, text-styling

When setting custom fonts for a textview, I can only choose normal, bold or italic:
[image]

How can I set the style to be **light** instead of bold in the following example?

```
<TextViewWithCustomFont
...
android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Comment: Use a combination of them e.g. `android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"` or `android:textStyle="normal|bold"`, you have more than 10 combinations.

Comment: @g00dy there are only 4 combinations. `normal` , `bold`, `italic` and `bold|italic`. In code this is `Typeface.BOLD`, `Typeface.ITALIC`, `Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC` and `Typeface.NORMAL`. Because these are Integers and bold being 1 and italic being 2 and bolditalic being 3 then `Typeface.ITALIC|Typeface.BOLD == Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC`

Comment: @g00dy, `android:textStyle="normal|bold"` just give a bold???

Answer (score 72):

This is font specific. Not all fonts have a **light**, **medium**, **thin** attribute/style, but the default font should. You can use the default light font by using `fontFamily: sans-serif-light` or for thin, `fontFamily: sans-serif-thin`.

For custom fonts, you would need to include the light version of the font and use it.

Comment: how about for semi-bold?

Comment: @Sam: use android:fontFamily="@font/robotomedium" (or "sans-serif-medium") but remember to remove android:textStyle="bold" (these two attributes are not exclusive)

Answer (score -1):

### Letter Spacing

As an adjacent solution to change a font's looks, you could use `letterSpacing`. This will change the distance between the letters within a TextView.

A positive number like 0.2 will add more of a gap, while negative like -0.1 will squish the letters together.

In Android 21+ you can programmatically call [setLetterSpacing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLetterSpacing(float)) or in XML add [letterSpacing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:letterSpacing).

Answer (score -3):

You can only combine those three attributes :

- normal
- bold
- italic

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textStyle

So it can be :

- normal
- bold
- italic
- bold | italic

Comment: I know what it can be. I'm asking how to set other styles for custom fonts that have other styles.

Comment: @kilaka: "I'm asking how to set other styles for custom fonts that have other styles" -- Android does not support such a concept, unless those "other styles" are split out into separate font files, loaded individually.

Comment: @CommonsWare - If the font files are loaded individually, there's no meaning to `style` - just the typeface. This means that the style attribute is useless in custom fonts.

Comment: @CommonsWare - thanks. I conclude that there is no custom typeface **family** - just a specific font. This is strange. Why have built in families but no support for custom families?