# How to set font weight programmatically?

Tags: android-studio

I want to change the font weight in TextView but i can't find the required method.

How can i do it without creating a new font?

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947165/how-to-set-font-weight-as-light-regular-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the right answer. There is the static method:

> open static fun create(family: Typeface?, weight: Int, italic: Boolean): Typeface

For example, if you want the font weight to be 700:

```
var text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)
text.typeface=Typeface.create(null,700,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can only show a TextView as Light, Regular and Condensed if the font that you're referencing allows those styles.**

private TextView AB;

Typeface someFontName-condensed = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "assets/NameOfFont-condensed.ttf");

AB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
AB.setTypeface(someFontName-condensed);